# Vue: An empty option should remain selectabe

Tags: vue.js, jquery-select2, html-select

I have a document with many input fields. Some are dependent on another, i.e. when in the first input field an option is selected, the second one should give the corresponding options based on a database query. This works fine.

Now I want to add for the second input field an empty option, which should remain selectable when the first option is selected.

So far I have this solution:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label for="ed_kbid" class="control-label">Bereich</label>
        <select2    v-model="bereichId":options="bereiche"  name="ed_kbid">
            <option disabled selected value="0">Select one</option>
        </select2>
    </div>
</template>
```

But the “Select one” disappears when in the first box is something selected.
How can I make it permanent?

Thanks!

edit:

```
<script>
import JQuery from 'jquery'
import Select2 from '@/components/Select2.vue'

let $ = JQuery

export default {
name: 'Bereich',

components: {
    Select2
},

data: function () {
    return {
        bereiche: [],
        kundeUebertrag: '',
        bereichId: 0
        
    }
},


computed: {
    kundeInputStore: function() 
    {
        return this.$store.state.kundeInputStore
        
    }
},

watch:{
    kundeInputStore: function() {
        let vm = this;
        vm.kundeUebertrag = vm.kundeInputStore;
        
        
        $.getJSON("/api/get_bereich.php", {kundeUebertrag: 
                   this.kundeUebertrag } , function(result){
            vm.bereiche = result;
    
        });
        
    },

    bereichId: function(value){
        this.$store.commit('setBereichInput', value)
    }

},
}
</script>
```

and the Select2-component:

```
<template>
<select class="form-control" >
    <slot></slot>
</select>
</template>


<script>
import JQuery from 'jquery'

let $ = JQuery

export default {
    name: 'select2',
    props: ['options', 'value'],


    mounted: function () {
        var vm = this
        $(this.$el)
        // init select2
            .select2({
                data: this.options,
                tags:true

            })
            // emit event on change.
            .on('change', function () {
                vm.$emit('input', this.value)
            })
        console.log( $(this.$el))

    },
    watch: {
        value: function (value) {
            // update value
            //console.log(value)
            $(this.$el)
                .val(value)
                .trigger('change')
        },
        options: function (options) {
            // update options
            $(this.$el).empty().select2({data: options,tags: true})
        }
    },
    destroyed: function () {
        $(this.$el).off().select2('destroy')
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Provide the "Select one" related code

Comment: I have edited the post ...

Comment: Ref: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/Lgxrcc5p/

Comment: I am creating the options via the Select2 component, so the solution doesn't fit to my case..

Comment: I just wanna mention: you shouldn't mix Vue and jQuery. Vue is based on creating a virtual DOM and maintaining it, while jQuery is based on manipulating the DOM directly. There's no functionality the jQuery offers that Vue does not either offer straight out of the box or have a plugin for doing (in a Vue friendly manner I might add).

Comment: Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

A little late but you can use:

```
<option :value="undefined">Select One</option>
```

then you can do a "for loop" for the other options that need to be rendered:

```
<option :value="undefined"></option>
<option v-for="o in o.select_options" v-bind:value=o.option_value>{{o.option_name}}</option>
```